# Avoid Deadlock with MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Spring JDBC

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I am having some trouble avoiding deadlocking when doing an "upsert" via Spring Boot/JPA and MySQL. I am calling the method in my service layer asynchronously so it is possible that a single request can call the upsert multiple times concurrently and I can also have many requests coming in concurrently. Performance is a consideration too. What do I need to do to avoid deadlocking?

Here is my Spring JPA method:

```java
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO message_resource (organizationId, messageId, bucket, friendlyName, fullPathName, uuid, md5, contentType, reference, size, created, updated)\n" +
        "VALUES (:organizationId, :messageId, :bucket, :friendlyName, :fullPathName, :uuid, :md5, :contentType, :reference, :size, :created, :updated)\n" +
        "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), friendlyName=:friendlyName, uuid=:uuid, md5=:md5, contentType=:contentType, reference=:reference, size=:size, created=:created, updated=:updated", nativeQuery = true)
int upsert(
        @Param("organizationId") long organizationId,
        @Param("messageId") long messageId,
        @Param("bucket") String bucket,
        @Param("friendlyName") String friendlyName,
        @Param("fullPathName") String fullPathName,
        @Param("uuid") String uuid,
        @Param("md5") String md5,
        @Param("contentType") String contentType,
        @Param("reference") String reference,
        @Param("size") long size,
        @Param("created") long created,
        @Param("updated") long updated);
```

Here is my Service Layer call:

```java
@Async
public void upsert() throws IOException {

    ...

    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    messageResourceRepository.upsert(
            mediaObject.getOrganizationId(),
            mediaObject.getMessageId(),
            messageResourceEntity.getBucket(),
            messageResourceEntity.getFriendlyName(),
            messageResourceEntity.getFullPathName(),
            messageResourceEntity.getUuid(),
            messageResourceEntity.getMd5(),
            messageResourceEntity.getContentType(),
            messageResourceEntity.getReference(),
            messageResourceEntity.getSize(),
            messageResourceEntity.getCreated(),
            messageResourceEntity.getUpdated()
    );

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
    ...
}
```

Comment: you sure about the transactional just above the repository method?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of mysql 5.7, you should use normal insert instead.

see here: https://sadlil.com/blog/mysql-deadlock/